# A line OA of length $ r$ starts from its initial position OX and traces an angle...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

A line OA of length $ r$ starts from its initial position OX and  traces an angle AOB=$\alpha$ in the anticlockwise direction.It then  traces back in the clockwise direction an angle BOC=3 $\theta $(where alpha is greater than 3 $\theta$).L is the foot of the perpendicular form C on OA.

Also $\frac{\sin ^3 \theta}{CL} = \frac{\cos^3 \theta}{OL} = 1$

1) $ \frac{1-r\cos \alpha }{r \sin \alpha} $ is equal to..

answer is $\tan 2\theta $

2)$ \frac{2r\sin \alpha }{1+2r\cos \alpha} $ is equal to..

answer is $\tan 2\theta $

3)$ \frac{2r^2 - 1}{r } $  is equal to ..

answer is $\cos \alpha $

So I have found out that CL is $ r sin( \alpha - 3\theta) $ and OL is  $ r cos( \alpha - 3\theta) $
I have tried substituting r with different ways. They don't work out. I have tried constructing a right triangle OBP  and solving it.  I have tried messing with area.

I have no idea how to title this question. Please help me with that.

[image]

Comment: It is not clear which quantities are known and can be used in the answers. Should everything be written as a function of $\theta$ and $r$?

Comment: @Aretino you're right, my bad. For first two theta is known for last alpha. I will change the question to include answers as well.